# How to make predictions with parameters obtained from a zero-inflated Poisson model with Bayesian approach?

Tags: r, bayesian, poisson-regression, zero-inflation, jags

I have a dataset with one response variable and one explanatory variable. Here is my zero-inflated Poisson model with a Bayesian approach.

```
bayes_mod_string = " model {

    for (i in 1:length(response)) {
        response[i] ~ dpois(mu[i])                    # the response variable follows a Poisson distribution
        mu[i] = lambda[i]*z[i] + 0.00001
        z[i] ~ dbern(w)                               # w is the weight (proportion) for non-zero values
        log(lambda[i]) = int + b_coeff*explanatory[i] # int is the intercept and b_coeff is the coefficient
    }
    
    int ~ dnorm(0.0, 1.0/1e6)                   # prior for int
    b_coeff~ dnorm(0.0, 1.0/1e4)                # prior for b_coeff
    w ~ dunif(0, 1)                             # prior for w
  
} "
# compling and running model
data_jags = as.list(train_set[1:1000, ])

params = c("int", "b_coeff", "w")

bayes_mod_string = jags.model(textConnection(bayes_mod_string), 
                              data = data_jags, n.chains = 3)
update(bayes_mod_string, 1e2)

bayes_mod_sim = coda.samples(model = bayes_mod_string,
                             variable.names = params, n.iter = 2e3)
bayes_mod_csim = as.mcmc(do.call(rbind, bayes_mod_sim))
```

How can I predict new values after obtaining the parameters?

Thank you.